# Interpretation of an lmer output

Tags: r, statistics, output, lme4, mixed-models

I'm new here, I've tried to run a lmer model:

```
lmer = lmer(RI ~ SET + LOG_VP + (1|API) + (1|ODOUR), data = a)
```

Could someone help me interpret the output?

```
  Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod'] 
Formula: RI ~ SET + LOG_VP + (1 | API) + (1 | ODOUR)
Data: a
REML criterion at convergence: -349.9
Scaled residuals: 
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.6167 -0.4719 -0.0357  0.5053  8.4850 
Random effects:
Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
API      (Intercept) 0.01431  0.11964 
ODOUR    (Intercept) 0.00415  0.06442 
Residual             0.00778  0.08820 
Number of obs: 238, groups:  API, 34; ODOUR, 14
Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  0.15716    0.08792   1.787
SET          0.08180    0.05490   1.490
LOG_VP       0.03527    0.01968   1.792
Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr) SET   
SET    -0.950       
LOG_VP  0.083 -0.049
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what your research question is, but

- the response when both fixed effects are zero is is 0.15716
- a 1 unit change in `SET` is associated with a 0.08180 change in `RI`
- a 1 unit change in `LOG_VP` is associated with a 0.03527 change in `RI`
- Variance at the `API` level is 0.01431
- Variance at the `ODOUR` level is 0.00415
- Residual (unit level) variance is 0.00778

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm interested in seeing wether the predictor SET has an influence on my response RI

Comment: You're welcome. So a 1 unit change in `SET` is associated with a 0.0818 change in the response.